# Mass dissolving of quads into a single point

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, vertices

I have created a mesh via sculpting, then converted all of the resulting tris into quads. However, it left me with a less-than-ideal overall layout.[image: A section of my current mesh]

The problem, as you can see, is that while most of the mesh is constructed from perfect rectangular quads in the exact layout that I'd like, but every so often there's an "odd one out" sort of situation.

I know exactly how I'd like to go about solving this problem. If a single vertex were to be created in the middle of each of these twisted quads, as I've manually done to this one:[image: Vertex created][image: Form new faces around vertex][image: Dissolve the edges around the original problem quad][image: Result of the operation]

Then this entire issue would simply vanish. However, this is a 10,000-polycount mesh; I'd prefer not to have to manually do this for every single repeat of this issue.

So, my question is: does Blender happen to have any methods, perhaps a setting for a modifier or something, that would be able to en-masse collapse these broken quads in the method I described or something similar?

Comment: Hard to see the topology of your mesh, which in a quad layout is defined by the 3 and 5 pole nodes. (eg the cube is all 3s).  For the quads above that have two 3s and two fives, select the 3s and [merge at center](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merging)  To do this _en masse_ may need to consider a scripting solution.

Comment: Ooh! That's a good idea. I didn't know about the "Merge at center" option. I may not be patient enough to go through a five-step process on every single problem child, but a single "Shift-R" per imperfection is something I am definitely willing to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the Decimate modifier, but to get clean topology, I am afraid you will have to do it manually, consider a complete retopology of your sculpture. If you decide to fix your mesh, you can speed up the merging process that batFINGER posted in the comments, by using Shift+R you can repeat the last action, thus reducing one step of the merging process. Which normally you will have to press Alt+M and then "Merge at Center", with this you only do it once, and next time it's just Shift+R.

[image]

The decimate modifier could get you some results quick, but you will have to keep an eye out for your topology, if you decide to use this method. Keep in mind that it may decimate already good topology you had. Also experiment with the three modes decimate has, "Collapse", "Un-Subdivide" and "Planar".

[image]

Comment: A combination of "Decimate" and "Remesh" is, unfortunately, what got me in this mess in the first place. It's still a thousand times better than the totally incoherent topology that I had before, but these occasional imperfections are still causing  very noticeable issues with putting on a normal-mapped material. However, as I mentioned in response to batFINGER, I'm definitely willing to go through and manually collapse all of these points given that "Merge at Center" is an option. Thank you!